# USB HDD Enclosure works with Ubuntu, but not Raspbian

Tags: ubuntu, usb, hard-disk, raspbian

SOLVED:
Even though the enclosure came with its own power supply, it required a powered USB hub, probably for some internal components that don't draw power from the main supply.

I have this dual HDD enclosure.

http://www.raidsonic.de/data/products/icybox/IB-3620/E_IB-3620_Series_manual_v1.1.pdf

Basic model IB-3620U3.

The enclosure implements JBOD(single) so the installed drives are seen separately by the OS.

I have no problems when I plug the device into my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, I can see both HDDs and the "usb" LED(that shows it is connected by USB) lights up on the device.

However, when I plug the device into my Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian, the HDDs are not seen and even the "usb" LED on the front of the device does not light.

### Outputs (pastebin urls)

#### Raspbian:

[`lsusb`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AAwXqFKn)
[`dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AyHJM3NJ)
[`uname -a`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zN9g2G16)
[`fdisk -l`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=41NxvDqk) (just SD card)

#### Ubuntu(laptop):

[`lsusb`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NEqj4tGz)
[`dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AvyRW7FA)
[`uname -a`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=w7YRTHJ4)
[`fdisk -l`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xYPF9DVZ)

**Note:** If I power up the device, while already plugged into my raspberry pi, the device's "usb" LED lights up, but there is no difference.

**Note2:** I know the device doesn't officially support Linux, but hardly anything does on the box. I have 2 of these USB HDD docks which work perfectly with Raspbian.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Optimized-Inateck-Including-Comaptible-Tool-Free/dp/B00GIDNLI6/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1403606340&sr=1-1&keywords=inateck+dock

**Note3:** One drive is ext4, and the other is NTFS.

Thank you for any help getting this thing working in Raspbian

#### Edit:

As requested, here is
[`lsmod(unplugged)`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zwLnWUFU)
[`lsmod(plugged-in)`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NCL7PRE9)
on the Ubuntu laptop.

And, [`lsmod(unplugged)`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=snj4KTAt), for raspbian. Doesn't change after plugging the device in.

At a glance, it looks like the top modules `usb-storage`, `ccm`, and `ctr`, are the only ones to change on the laptop when plugging the device in.

Where do I got from here ?

Comment: The issue is likely b/c you're missing kernel modules (drivers) on Rasp. that you have loaded by default or are avail. on Ubuntu. Take a look at the outputs of `lsmod` on both systems.

Comment: @slm Thanks for the help. I added `lsmod` outputs for both systems.

Comment: I'd start with the module `usb_storage`.

Comment: I should have said that I'm a bit of a noob with poking around Linux internals. `sudo modprobe usb_storage` gives no errors yet `lsmod` does not show the module loaded.

Comment: NP. Can you run `locate usb_storage`? Do you have this `.ko` file?

Comment: `locate usb_storage` returns nothing. EDIT: this also returns nothing on the ubuntu laptop

Comment: Sorry this is the actual module: `usb-storage.ko`.

Comment: np, Raspbian still returns nothing, and my laptop finds 4 results,
`/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko` and the same for `3.13.0.24` `3.13.0-27` `3.13.0.29`

Comment: Yeah the laptop is finding multiple vers. b/c there are multiple linux kernels installed.

Comment: Research is leading me to believe this is your issue: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/why-doesnt-my-external-hard-drive-appear-in-dev

Comment: How would that be ? I'm aware that the raspberry pi cannot supply much power to usb devices, however, the device I'm using has its own power supply .

Comment: @slm Apologies ! You were in fact, correct ! see main post !

Comment: consider moving your revelation out of the question and add as an answer so this question stops appearing for others looking for questions to answer.

Or, put your revelation earlier in the question, and/or change the title. :)